# ZF2 module best practices

Tags: zend-framework2

What is the accepted best practice with the Zend Framework's new module system in version 2?  Is it the intention that I create one module per controller for my application, or am I supposed to use the modules to group related controllers and their models together in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Rob Allens introduction into Modules](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/modules-in-zf2/) or [Matthews introduction into Modules](http://www.mwop.net/blog/267-Getting-started-writing-ZF2-modules.html).

In Short: A module is simply a bunch of Classes that perform one specific task. I.E.: A `Guestbook` could be one Module. `GuestbookMailing` could be another module (but doesn't **need** to be). You can have multiple Controllers, Models, Views in your Module. But it should be all tied to one part of your whole application.